# How to remove app shortcut from home screen (modded trebuchet launcher) after installing as system app

Tags: launcher, app-icons, hidden, trebuchet

This tablet is proprietary, so the launcher is custom (modded trebuchet) and very limited. It runs Android 8.1.

I was able to get apex launcher installed, along with root access, but I'm trying to avoid using a third-party launcher because if I rename it with app cloner it tends to glitch out.

The goal is for my exploit of this tablet to be as undetectable as possible, which is why I am renaming all apps I've installed.

I noticed that system apps don't show up on the stock launcher home screen, and since I can't use apex or some other launcher, I figured I would install all my wanted apps (Facebook, telegram, etc...) as system apps.

I was able to install them as system apps with lucky patcher, however they still show on the home screen.. Any ideas for how I can modify the system under the hood, or otherwise, and keep these apps from showing on the stock (modded trebuchet) launcher?

Comment: By desktop (which is a term specific to Windows and its counterparts) do you mean home screen or app drawer? Or does your modded launcher shows all apps on home screen (iOS style)? Anyhow, if a system app is not showing up in app drawer then it means that it has no default launchable activity (meaning it is not designed to be interacted with by user). FB, Telegram, they all have default launchable activities, so making them a system app won't make a difference.

Comment: @Firelord Yes, I did mean home screen or app drawer. Sorry, I'm a web developer still getting acquainted with this side of the street. So is there any way to remove/modify the default launchable activity? For instance, if I were to use apktools or jadx to decompile/recompile, is there a specific area I could look to modify this behavior? Thanks